# Store large number of data in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ios7

I am creating an app for existing eCommerce web site like amazon,flipkart, etc,. I am thinking to store some part of information in local storage after the first REST API call to reduce the API calls and save time to show UI faster. I am wondering what could be the best way to store products information in local storage or relay on REST calls? If its local storage which is the best method or approach to handle data effectively and speed in performance?

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious solution is Core Data and link that to SQLite, which is built into the OS. There's lots of good books and web pages on this.

However, if you're not time critical and open to new ideas, and your APIs are JSON based, then maybe take a look at CouchDB. This is a free-form database that stores and retrieves data in JSON format natively, and you can query it using JSON, etc.

In this case I would prefix all API calls with a call to the DB, which simply sees if that object exists and is reasonably up to date. If it is, you simply use that object. If not, you use the API to retrieve it, store that in the DB, and continue as if it were always there.

In any case, you need to decide how to handle old data and keep the store clean.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. As it has tons of data related to the product, Is the EAV Structure can be used here to store product information? See link for ref: http://inchoo.net/magento/magentos-database-layout-and-its-eav-structure/

Comment: It looks to me like this is a classic SQL back-end. Core Data and SQLite appear to be the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You also can check a [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit). It allows you to easily parse JSON responses and save the data in CoreData. But you will have to check yourself is a saved data up-to-date or not.